# EOFError: EOF when reading a line error when using subprocess for SSH

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

Im using a windows machine trying to SSH to an Ubuntu Server using PKI. I will run test.py which will ask for a number. This is my code that I will execute on the local machine.

```
import subprocess

command = "ssh -t soon@x.x.x.x echo 'soon' | sudo -S python3.7 ./Desktop/test.py"

command = command.split()

out = subprocess.check_output(["scp", "final_compile.py", "soon@x.x.x.x.x:./Desktop"])

run_script = subprocess.run(command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, input = "1", text=True)
```

test.py:

```
import subprocess

choice = input("Choose a number: ")

if choice == 1:
    result = subprocess.run(['cat' '/etc/passwd'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
    print(result.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
```

After executing this code I am returned with `EOFError: EOF when reading a line` How do I solve this error?

Comment: Just splitting things on words doesn't make it an `execv`-capable argument list. You need to actually have it be a _single simple command without any shell directives_. `|` is a shell directive.

Comment: Also, if we interpreted it naively, your original code would only be running `echo` on the other side of the SSH connection, but running `sudo -S python3.7` locally!

Comment: BTW, you don't need `sudo` to read `/etc/passwd` at all; it's `/etc/shadow` that requires privileges.

Comment: ...anyhow -- if you want to run `echo 'soon' | sudo -S python3.7 ./Desktop/test.py` on the remote system, pass **that exact string as an argument to `ssh`**. As in: `command = [ 'ssh', '-t', 'soon@x.x.x.x', '''echo 'soon' | sudo -S python3.7 ./Desktop/test.py''']`. The `|` needs to be **part of the argument to ssh**.

Comment: ...beyond that, though, when you run `echo 'soon' | ...`, that means that the TTY is reading from `echo`, not reading from the user, so `input("Choose a number:")` can no longer read from the user at all; instead, any time a program on the right-hand side of the pipeline tries to read content from stdin, it gets anything left in the pipe from `echo`, or an EOF if that pipeline has been exhausted.

Comment: ...now, if you use the `-tt` arguments to `echo` to force it to use a TTY, and your parent process really has a true TTY, then you might be able to redirect your stdin from `/dev/tty` to get a handle on the TTY, but it's not a good practice to depend on that working.

Comment: ...so: There's a lot of separate things wrong here, and most have already been asked and answered separately and are already in the knowledge base. Please try to ask a more focused, narrow question.

Comment: I think I get what you mean